# Why I get RAM leakage while running Yolov5 tensorflow inference server (FASTAPI) with docker?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, memory-leaks, fastapi

I got the following code for running inference server with FastApi. In about 8 hours my RAM memory increases by 4Gi.

What is more interesting - when I stop my container RAM memory does not clean.

For instance, before running docker container I get 2 Gi RAM used, as soon as I run docker container memory increases up to 4Gi and then starts slowly grow. (8 hours - 8Gi RAM). After stoping container I still get 6 RAM used... It means that I get around 4Gi RAM leakage.

Where could be my problem?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
import yaml
import time
from loguru import logger
import tracemalloc

# from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response
from PIL import Image
import os
import io
import json
import base64
import gc


# tf.config.gpu.set_per_process_memory_fraction(0.75) 

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

# ========= Функция для обработки сырой картинки и подготовки ее для инференса =========
def letterbox(im, new_shape=(640, 640), color=(114, 114, 114), auto=True, scaleFill=False, scaleup=True, stride=32):
    # Resize and pad image while meeting stride-multiple constraints
    shape = im.shape[:2]  # current shape [height, width]
    if isinstance(new_shape, int):
        new_shape = (new_shape, new_shape)

    # Scale ratio (new / old)
    r = min(new_shape[0] / shape[0], new_shape[1] / shape[1])
    if not scaleup:  # only scale down, do not scale up (for better val mAP)
        r = min(r, 1.0)

    # Compute padding
    ratio = r, r  # width, height ratios
    new_unpad = int(round(shape[1] * r)), int(round(shape[0] * r))
    dw, dh = new_shape[1] - new_unpad[0], new_shape[0] - new_unpad[1]  # wh padding
    if auto:  # minimum rectangle
        dw, dh = np.mod(dw, stride), np.mod(dh, stride)  # wh padding
    elif scaleFill:  # stretch
        dw, dh = 0.0, 0.0
        new_unpad = (new_shape[1], new_shape[0])
        ratio = new_shape[1] / shape[1], new_shape[0] / shape[0]  # width, height ratios

    dw /= 2  # divide padding into 2 sides
    dh /= 2

    if shape[::-1] != new_unpad:  # resize
        im = cv2.resize(im, new_unpad, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    top, bottom = int(round(dh - 0.1)), int(round(dh + 0.1))
    left, right = int(round(dw - 0.1)), int(round(dw + 0.1))
    im = cv2.copyMakeBorder(im, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=color)  # add border
    return im, ratio, (dw, dh)

# ========= Функция для загрузки весов модели =========
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
 
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
    return graph

# ========= Класс конфига =========
class create_config():
    def __init__(self, file):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            data = yaml.safe_load(f)
        self.modelPath = data['modelPath']
        self.logFile = data['logFile']
        self.loggingLevel = data['loggingLevel']
        self.host = data['host']
        self.port = data['port']

# ========= Функция обработки результатов YOLO =========
def YOLOdetect(output_data):  # input = interpreter, output is boxes(xyxy), classes, scores
    output_data = output_data[0]                # x(1, 25200, 7) to x(25200, 7)
    boxes = np.squeeze(output_data[..., :4])    # boxes  [25200, 4]
    scores = np.squeeze( output_data[..., 4:5]) # confidences  [25200, 1]
    classes = classFilter(output_data[..., 5:]) # get classes
#     Convert nx4 boxes from [x, y, w, h] to [x1, y1, x2, y2] where xy1=top-left, xy2=bottom-right
    x, y, w, h = boxes[..., 0], boxes[..., 1], boxes[..., 2], boxes[..., 3] #xywh
    xyxy = [x - w / 2, y - h / 2, x + w / 2, y + h / 2]  # xywh to xyxy   [4, 25200]

    return xyxy, scores, classes  # output is boxes(x,y,x,y), classes(int), scores(float) [predictions length] 

# ========= Функция отбора чисто классов =========
def classFilter(classdata):
    classes = []  # create a list
    for i in range(classdata.shape[0]):         # loop through all predictions
        classes.append(classdata[i].argmax())   # get the best classification location
    return classes  # return classes (int)      

# ========= Функция масштабирования координат на изначальное разрешение картинки =========
def scale_coords(img1_shape, coords, img0_shape, ratio_pad=None):
    # Rescale coords (xyxy) from img1_shape to img0_shape
    if ratio_pad is None:  # calculate from img0_shape
        gain = min(img1_shape[0] / img0_shape[0], img1_shape[1] / img0_shape[1])  # gain  = old / new
        pad = (img1_shape[1] - img0_shape[1] * gain) / 2, (img1_shape[0] - img0_shape[0] * gain) / 2  # wh padding
    else:
        gain = ratio_pad[0][0]
        pad = ratio_pad[1]

    coords[:, [0, 2]] -= pad[0]  # x padding
    coords[:, [1, 3]] -= pad[1]  # y padding
    coords[:, :4] /= gain
    clip_coords(coords, img0_shape)
    return coords 

# ========= Функция ограничивающая координаты =========
def clip_coords(boxes, shape):
    # Clip bounding xyxy bounding boxes to image shape (height, width)
    
    boxes[:, [0, 2]] = boxes[:, [0, 2]].clip(0, shape[1])  # x1, x2
    boxes[:, [1, 3]] = boxes[:, [1, 3]].clip(0, shape[0])  # y1, y

# ========= Класс модели =========
class Yolov5:
    @logger.catch
    def __init__(self, model_weight):
        self.model_weight = model_weight
        self._start()

    @logger.catch        
    def _start(self):
        logger.error(' ========= PIZDETS ========= ')
        self.graph = load_graph(self.model_weight)
        self.x = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/x:0')
        self.y = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/Identity:0')
        # self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session('', self.graph) 
        self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=self.graph, config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

    @logger.catch
    def forward(self, image):    
        y_out = self.sess.run(self.y, feed_dict={self.x: image})
        return y_out

    @logger.catch
    def process_image(self, im0):        
        im = letterbox(im0, (640,640), stride=32, auto=False)[0]  # padded resize
        h, w = im.shape[:2]
        # im = im[..., ::-1]  # HWC to CHW, BGR to RGB
        im = np.ascontiguousarray(im)  # contiguous
        im = im.astype('float32')
        im /= 255  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
        if len(im.shape) == 3:
            im = im[None]  # expand for batch dim
            
        return im, cv2.cvtColor(im0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), h, w, im0.shape
        
    @logger.catch
    def postprocess(self, y, h, w, old_shape):
        y = [x if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) else x.numpy() for x in y]
        y[0][..., :4] *= [w, h, w, h]  # xywh normalized to pixels
        xyxy, scores, classes = YOLOdetect(y)
        xyxy = np.array(xyxy).T
        
        indexes = tf.image.non_max_suppression(xyxy, scores, max_output_size=10, iou_threshold=0.5, score_threshold=0.3)
        filtered_xyxy = xyxy[indexes, :]
        filtered_scores = scores[np.array(indexes)]
        
        scaled_xyxy = scale_coords((h,w), filtered_xyxy, old_shape).round()
        
        return scaled_xyxy, filtered_scores

    @logger.catch
    def run_local(self, image):
        # PREPROCESS
        im, im0, h, w, old_shape = self.process_image(image)
        # INFERENCE
        y = self.forward(im)
        # POSTPROCESS
        coords, scores = self.postprocess(y, h, w, old_shape)
        return coords, scores

config = create_config('extra/config.yml')
# print('======= Config created =======')
# model = Yolov5(config.modelPath)
# print('======= Model loaded =======')
# print('======= GPU MEMORY =======',  tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage('GPU:0'))

# image_path = 'extra/test_image.jpg'

# # Загружаем изображение с помощью CV2
# image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# TOTAL_IMAGES = 10000
# start = time.time()
# # INFERENCE
# for _ in range(TOTAL_IMAGES):
#     model.run_local(image)
# end = time.time()

# # print('======= GPU MEMORY =======',  tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage('GPU:0'))
# print('======= TOTAL TIME =======',  end - start)
# print('======= TIME PER IMAGE =======',  (end - start) / TOTAL_IMAGES)

#===============================================================================================================
# Logger setup
logger.add(config.logFile, format="{time} {level} {message}", level=config.loggingLevel)


import io
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class PredictRequest(BaseModel):
    img: str
    targetPercent: float

def get_prediction(image):
    with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
        results = model.run_local(image)
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
        return results

@app.post("/predict/")
async def predict_image(request: PredictRequest):
    base64_image = request.img
    conf_threshold = request.targetPercent
    img_data = base64.b64decode(base64_image)
    image_np = np.frombuffer(img_data, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(image_np, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    results = get_prediction(image)
    
    res = []

    
    for coord, score in zip(results[0], results[1]):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = list(map(int, coord))
        confidence = float(score)

        if confidence >= conf_threshold:
            res.append({'pointMin' : (x1, y1), 'pointMax' : (x2, y2), 'label' : "people", 'percent' : confidence})

    del results, img_data, image_np, image
    gc.collect()

    return json.dumps({'params' : res})

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.info('starting yolov5 webservice... (TF)')
    logger.info(f"cuda is available: {len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) != 0}")

    try:
        model = Yolov5(config.modelPath)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"couldn't load model weights with error {e}")

    uvicorn.run(app, host=config.host, port=config.port)
```